# How to build navigation menu by webservice response content?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web-services

My goal is to retrieve both the navigation menu bar and the content to show from a backend `REST` webservice.

How can I achieve it? I have the following code, but which does not work so far:

testpage.html:

```
<div ng-controller="testController>
    <li ng-repeat="nav in navs">
        <a href="{{nav.link}}">{{nav.name}}</a>
    </li>
</div>
<!-- content... -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/navigationService.js"></script>
<script src="js/testController.js"></script>
```

main.js:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/test", {
        templateUrl : "templates/testpage.html",
        controller : "testController"
    }).otherwise({
        templateUrl : "templates/error.html"
    });
});
```

navigationService.js:

```
angular.module("test").service('navigationService', function(data) {
    this.initNavigation = function(data) { //assume a json object with fields is passed
        //process the data and apply some modifications, then set the scope variable to init the menu
        $scope.navs = data; 
    }
});
```

testController.js:

```
angular.module("test").conroller('testController', ['$scope', '$http', 'navigationService', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get(url)
        .success(function(data) {
            navigationService.initNavigation(data.navs); //creates navigation from json
            //process the content
    });
}]);
```

Questions:

- how do I properly initialize the `navigationService`? I lateron want to use this service in multiple controllers.
  Should I place the service inside the main.js, or should I leave it inside the single file?
- how can I trigger the menu generation in the `testpage.html` when the json is retrieved and initialized by the `navigationService`?

Comment: You've missed out the "navigationService" in the callback function of controller.

Comment: Could you add an example of what you mean?